# Selenide - How to run it with a headless Chrome?

Tags: java, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless, selenide

We are trying to developer an automation test, and we found [Selenide](http://selenide.org/) an interesting and easy framework for running the UI tests.

Selenide needs as an input the browser to use.

So we are passing 2 arguments to the program:

```
selenide.browser=Chrome
webdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe
```

And the code looks something like that:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",inputParams.get("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
System.setProperty("selenide.browser", inputParams.get("selenide.browser"));

open("http://example.com:8080/myPages");
```

All works fine, but we also need it to run in headless mode.

We tried several ways to run it in headless mode, (different param in the **selenide.browser**, **PhantomJs** and some other combinations, but with not success till now.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that in order to run Selenide in headless mode we need to add system property `selenide.headless=true`

Answer (score 1):

You could do also:

```
 Configuration.headless = true;
```